# TYPO3 realurl and tx_news, use title as entire path-segment

Tags: typo3, realurl, tx-news, typo3-8.x

I migrated a wordpress website, using the Yoast SEO plugin, to TYPO3 and the news articles have URL's that use only the domain and the title;

```
## example
http://example.com/news-title/
```

- I work with TYPO3 **v8.7.10**, tx_news **6.3.0** and realurl **2.3.1**
- I know how to hide the controller and action name by using fixedPostVars as described in [docs.typo3.org](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html#)
- of course I can do a permanant redirect with .htaccess
- I know the trick in the configuration with **`user_encodeSpURL_postProc`** and **`user_decodeSpURL_preProc`** but there I need at least one directory ...

does anybody knows any other option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this solution

**1) Skip not needed arguments**

By using the following setting

```
plugin.tx_news {
        settings {
                link {
                        skipControllerAndAction = 1
                }
        }
}
```

the links don't include the controller and action anymore. I prefer to use this instead of removing it in realurl because of less magic in realurl.

**2.) Render the single view on the homepage**

*Just for clarification: As homepage is the meant the 1st page.*

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0] && [globalVar = TSFE:id = HOMEPAGE-ID]
  lib.news = USER
  lib.news {
                userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
                pluginName = Pi1
                vendorName = GeorgRinger
                extensionName = News
                controller = News
                settings =< plugin.tx_news.settings
                persistence =< plugin.tx_news.persistence
                view =< plugin.tx_news.view
                action = detail
                switchableControllerActions.News.1 = detail
  }
  page.10 < lib.news
[end]
```

This is just a proof of concept as the final integration depends on how render your templates & content. You could also remove the `page.10 < lib.news` and check the variable `lib.news` in your content or you assign it to the variables and check that in the templates.

Answer (score 1):

With the combination of

- use the news detail view on the start page and
- use the postFixedVars of RealURL (https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#fixedpostvars)

you are able to create such an URL.
But I would suggest not to use the start page and create redirects to e.g. http://example.com/article/news-title/.

Comment: smart thinking using the homepage for detail display ! that is probably the only way ... only that that is not really an option since I use the home for many other content ...

Comment: You can override content output with a simple ts condition

Comment: @GeorgRinger ... please supply the answer !!! I will assign you the credits if you have a solution !!